# How do I uninstall Neverwinter Nights on Windows 10?

Tags: neverwinter-nights

I installed the game from my diamond edition disc. It refuses to run no matter what I have it set at. Any version of windows, even administrator mode. I was able to uninstall the kingmaker module through add/remove programs, but when I try to do that with the game, it gives me a pop-up saying:

An uninstallation support file could not be installed.

Catastrophic failure

So, what am I supposed to do now? I can't play the game, and I can't remove it from my system. I also can't find an uninstaller in the game's folder. I don't know what else to do here.

Comment: Can you tell us what OS you're on?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to manually uninstall NEVERWINTER NIGHTS PLATINUM EDITION or NEVERWINTER NIGHTS DIAMOND EDITION, follow these steps:

1. Delete the folder where the game was installed
2. Remove the entry from the start menu
3. Remove the following Windows Registry key using RegEdit (Windows + R => regedit.exe):

MyComputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{C1583439-B034-4881-819C-D52A0587662B}

4. Remove the following Windows Registry key using RegEdit:

MyComputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BioWare\NWN\Neverwinter

5. Remove the hidden folder:

C:\Program Files\InstallShield Installation Information\{C1583439-B034-4881-819C-D52A0587662B}

(where C: is the drive on your system with the Program Files folder)

Now the game should be completely uninstalled, without any traces left (except maybe save game files).

**Update**:
If these do not work, try using [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/). This is one of the [suggested](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-gaming/an-installation-support-file-could-not-be/0c63fca3-aab1-4845-81fb-61e147ab79de) methods by Microsoft support.

Comment: I can't find the two registry keys. There is no Bioware folder in the area you mentioned. I did the last step prior while trying to figure out how to get it to uninstall. The program is still showing up in add/remove programs. Telling it to uninstall it does nothing.

Comment: Odd that telling it to uninstall doesn't do anything now. Typically, Windows is smart enough that if it cannot find uninstall files, it will ask if you want to remove the Program from Programs and Features.

Comment: I just tried to uninstall it again after rebooting my computer. A pop-up came up saying something about rundll32. Also, I've noticed that its not showing how much data the program is taking up, unlike every other program in the list.

Comment: if the bioware key is not in the location mentioned, then check under `HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\`

Comment: I don't see an 'HKLM' anywhere. I opened up all of the options, and didn't see a 'bioware' or 'atari' anywhere.

Comment: Try CCleaner. Link is in my updated answer.

Comment: Will the free version work, or would I have to get the paid version?

Comment: Free version will do just fine